# DataTables rows under deleted row gets undefined after a row is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a `datatable`. There is a `Delete button` on every row. As soon as I delete a row using `.remove()` function the respective row gets deleted, but afterwards on clicking the `Save button`, the rows below the deleted rows gets undefined.

Here is the sample code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<form method="POST"></form>
<div class="container">      
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable" id="example">
   <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type ="text" id="name_0" value ="hello0"/></td>
           <td><button id="btn_0" onclick="del(this);">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type ="text" id="name_1" value ="hello1"/></td>
            <td><button id="btn_1" onclick="del(this);">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type ="text" id="name_2" value ="hello2"/></td>
            <td><button id="btn_2" onclick="del(this);">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type ="text" id="name_3" value ="hello3"/></td>
            <td><button id="btn_3" onclick="del(this);">Delete</button></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave"/>
</div>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i =0;
$('#example').dataTable({ 
            "aoColumns": [
                            null, { "bSortable": false }
                        ],
            "aaSorting": [],
            "pageLength": 10,
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 200]

        });    

$('#btnSave').click(function(){ 
var tbl = $('#example').dataTable();
$(tbl.fnGetNodes()).each(function () { 

            alert($(this).find("#name_" + i).val());
            i++;
            });

    });
});

function del(element)
{
    var btnId = element.id;
    var idIndex = btnId.substring(btnId.indexOf("_") + 1);
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.row($($("#btn_" + idIndex)).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
}
```

Here is a non-working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53s39cab/6/) for the same.

How can I delete a row and then clicking on the `Save button`, the rows below the deleted row should not get undefined.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because there is a mismatch between row index and ID of the INPUT element after you delete the row.

Short workaround would be to use the following code instead:

```
alert($(this).find("input[type=text]").val());
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53s39cab/7/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').click(function () {
            $('#example tbody tr').each(function () {
                alert($(this).find("td:eq(0)").find('input').val());
            });
        });
    });

    function del(element) {
        $(element).closest('tr').remove();
    }
```